# How to use fread() with "https" url scheme?

Tags: r, https, data.table, fread

In R Documentation for fread() it's said that "input" argument may be a URL starting http:// or file://. However in this "[Introduction to data.table](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro-vignette.html)" vignette fread() is used with https:

```
flights <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/arunsrinivasan/flights/NYCflights14/flights14.csv")
```

That results in "Error in download.file(input, tt, mode = "wb") : unsupported URL scheme" console message.

I can't figure out how to make it work. I've tried settings options(download.file.method = "curl") or "auto", but nothing seems to help.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This has been implemented in `1.9.5`. You can install it by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: @Krome you can answer (and accept) your question to not leave it as open.

Comment: Thanks, @Jan, i'll do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by @Arun, this has been implemented in data.table v1.9.5. One can install it by following [these instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)