# fread() error loading csv from https URL on Windows - data.table R 1.9.5 "showProgress must be 1 or 0, currently"

Tags: r, ssl, https, data.table, fread

CONTEXT:

- Windows XP R 3.1.3 data.table package 1.9.5 (dev.)
- Rtools 3.1
- installed libraries `data.table`, `RCurl` installed certificate bundle
- and .pem file in RCurl directory, including it in Windows PATH

I'm trying to replicate basic `fread()` usage.

I was getting SSL certificate error although `download.file()` works fine with the same URL. Therefore I followed recommendations as shown in stack overflow:

[How to use fread() with "https" url scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370620/how-to-use-fread-with-https-url-scheme)

Now data.table 1.9.5 is installed. I do not get SSL error anymore but find error:

> Error in
>   fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/arunsrinivasan/flights/NYCflights14/flights14.csv",
>   :    showProgress must be 0 or 1, currently

Here is exactly what I typed in RStudio:

```
library (data.table)
setInternet2()
options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
flights <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/arunsrinivasan/flights/NYCflights14/flights14.csv")
```

I also tried forcing `showProgress=TRUE` or `FALSE` but still get same error.

Comment: Just checked again and the problem seems to be with fread() in version 1.9.5 and .csv files.

Comment: I also had this problem using `fread` from `dev` version on Windows 8.1 x64 (see my comments under Richard's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499145/can-i-prevent-data-tables-fread-column-class-inference-getting-overridden-by-tr)

Comment: There's already a bug report [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1111). I've tested on windows 8.1, and not able to reproduce.. Could you post your `sessionInfo()` output, and also re-run with `verbose=TRUE`? Also, what does `getOption("datatable.showProgress")` return?

Comment: @Arun; please excuse previous comment...I just retried the `dev` version on W8.1 and fread works as expected. 5 days ago i had the same issue as reported in the bug (and OP).... now its ok.

Comment: @user2957945, good to know, thanks. Manel, just tried on windows XP as well.. with the exact code you've shown.. can't reproduce the error :-(.